# JavaScript replace method disables line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with id `#container`, this div contains couple of strings/lines. I use the below code to hide a specific string inside that div.

```
$('div#container').text(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace('Some text to be hidden', '');
})
```

The problem is: by adding the above code, all other strings/lines in the div become joined together. i.e. line breaks are disabled. If I removed the code, the line breaks works fine.

How can I hide that specific string without disabling line breaks?

I tried to put \n like this: `return t.replace('Some text to be hidden', '\n');` but that didn't help.

Any suggestions? Answers are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're destroying all HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your search and replace on individual text nodes so you don't destroy the other child elements (like `<br>` or `<p>` tags) .

If the text nodes are immediate children of the `#container` object, then you can do that like this:

```
$('#container').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace('Some text to be hidden', '');
});
```

If the text nodes are deeper children, then we could only offer a simple answer if you show us the actual HTML you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this by using display none css`http://jsfiddle.net/gShM4/67/`

```
<div class="text">Good Stuff Some text to be hidden</br> above element is hide  </div>

$('div.text').html(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace('Some text to be hidden', '<span class="hidden"></span>');
})

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```